# Does react-router-dom automatically pass history object to children components inside Router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

This will probably be a rookie question but does Router component passes down the history object to child components automatically? to demonstrate I have this

App.js ;

```js
const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Hello</h1>
      <Router history={history}>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
          <Route path="/another_route" exact component={AnotherRoute} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </>
  );
};
```

and Home and Another Route components taking advantage of the history prop to re-route without explicitly being passed down to the children via Router.

```js
// Home.js

import React from "react";

const Home = (props) => {
  return (
    <>
      <h3> Hello From home </h3>
      <button onClick={() => props.history.push("/another_route")}>
        click here to go another route
      </button>
    </>
  );
};

export default Home;


// AnotherRoute.js

import React from "react";

const AnotherRoute = (props) => {
  return (
    <>
      <h3> Hello From this another Route </h3>
      <button onClick={() => props.history.push("/")}>
        click here to go back
      </button>
    </>
  );
};

export default AnotherRoute;
```

Everything functioning just fine, but I would like to understand this. I haven't seen it in the documentation explicitly.

here is a codesandbox I created for you to experiment:

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-dom-passes-history-object-to-children-automatically-jj7ih

thanks.

Comment: it does share history prop to its children

Comment: could u share a documentation page or something for me to verify this?

Comment: I have read that article and it talks about wrapping the component with withRouter component. if you would read my question and check the codesandbox I have not wrapped any component (or used useHistory hook) and it works just fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes
All Route render methods will be passed the same three route props , `match`
,`location`,`history`. So you can use these props in all the components you render with react-router-dom

**What are Route render methods?**

The recommended method of rendering something with a `<Route>` is to use children elements. There are, however, a few other methods you can use to render something with a `<Route>`like

```
<Route component>
<Route render>
<Route children> function
```

**What is your Route render method in your example?**

You have used `<Route component>` as `<Route path="/" exact component={Home} />`

[Official Docs](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-render-methods)